# Wix variable name formats with spaces and other characters

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wix, bootstrapper

I have a project I am trying to include in my WIX Bootstrapper.

The projects name is "Project-1 With Spaces"

In my WIX Bootstrapper i am trying to access this project like so

```
$(var.Project-1_With_Spaces.TargetDir)
```

This throws an error

```
Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.Project-1_With_Spaces.TargetDir)'
```

I believe it is the '-' character that is to blame, yet do not know how to format my variable correctly to be able to access this project. I have tried replacing '-' with underscores or removing it altogether with no luck.

Renaming the project is not possible and I don't think WIX variable naming conventions should force me to have to rename it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WIX variables can have spaces in, try using

```
$(var.Project-1 With Spaces.TargetDir)
```

Comment: That worked! I always assumed var names could not contain spaces so thought my issue was the '-' character!