# (Cannot) with Create Shortcut to start menu wix

Tags: xml, wix

I am inspired by http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html
still I cannot make it working... I get the Error 3 ICE69: '...\Mold Sentinel Control App.exe' references invalid file

The file is there, though ...
The complete xml is below

Thanks for helping

```
<DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
  <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="...">
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
       Name="Mold Sentinel Control App"
       Description="Mold Sentinel Controller"
        Target="[#Mold Sentinel Control App.exe]"
              WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY"/>
      <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
        Key="Software\Microsoft\Mold Sentine Control App" Name="installed" 
        Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: Have you check the syntaxis of  `Target="[#Mold Sentinel Control App.exe]"`, it looks like you should remove whitespaces. It could take `#Mold` instead of `#Mold Sentinel Control App.exe`

Comment: Where's your `<File ...>` element that defines `#Mold Sentinel Control App.exe` and what does it look like? As it says in the link you provided: *The Target attribute points to the executable to launch on disk. Notice how it references the full path using the `[#FileId]` syntax where `myapplication.exe` was **previously defined.***. And  I suspect it's not valid to have spaces in the Id, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies.Here it is the link to the installer files https://www.dropbox.com/s/vt2z3gxgmqwtvh0/Installer.7z?dl=0   About spaces: I have spaces in my application name, I never hear it is forbidden using spaces (which are used throughout the projet). The File tag is defined here<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <!-- Application Executable-->
      <Component Id="Exec" Guid="..." >
        <File Source="$(var.Mold Sentinel Control App.TargetPath)" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, whihc I cannot easily get rid of ...

Comment: Error 3 ICE69: 'C:\Users\user\Documents\svnRepos\prjs\Mold Sentinel\trunk\software\Mold Sentinel Control App\Mold Sentinel Control App\bin\Debug\Mold Sentinel Control App.exe' references invalid file. C:\Users\user\Documents\svnRepos\prjs\Mold Sentinel\trunk\software\Mold Sentinel Control App\Installer\Product.wxs 103 1 Installer

Comment: I tried then this          Target="[#$(var.Mold Sentinel Control App.TargetPath)]"
   Wix variables can have spaces https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561668/wix-variable-name-formats-with-spaces-and-other-characters

Comment: I make it work on removing the sharp '#' character in the Target .... what is # for? I cannot find in the web?

Comment: You don't want to mix `#` with `$(var....)`. They're different things. The prepended `#` is to reference an Id in some scenarios.